# Best way to compress MP3 sound files

Tags: ios, compression, mp3

I have an app (game) in the app store that is very large (over 250mb) and realized it's due to the sound files in it rather than the images. Is there any good way to compress mp3 files?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MP3 audio files are compressed. However, if you still have the original uncompressed audio and you used "default" settings convert it to MP3 the first time, it's quite possible that the result wasn't as small as it could be.

Try saving at a lower bitrate.

Try using mono samples instead of stereo.

Try using shorter samples repeated instead of a really long sample.